# React PropType with ESLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

Started using ESLint and running into couple of issues with PropType, currently I have a prop `children` and for now let's say this prop is a `string`. I'm getting an error `'children' is missing in props validationeslint(react/prop-types)`, to solve this I just use `PropTypes` like so:

```
CartProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
}
```

The above solves the issue and then I get another issue `propType "children" is not required, but has no corresponding defaultProps declaration.eslint(react/require-default-props)`

So to solve this I add another PropType like so:

```
CartProvider.defaultProps = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
}
```

So my understanding is that every time I use a prop I need to use `propType` and `defaultProps`. So ok this solves the issue with `string` based prop. But actually this prop is an `array` and then with `array` I'm getting other issues `Prop type`array`is forbiddeneslint(react/forbid-prop-types)`.

Please help me understand why does ESLint marking these props as errors, I know how to disabled it but I would like to understand why it's happening and then write better code.

Here is a sample project:

**CartContext**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export const CartContext = React.createContext(null)

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = React.useState(0)
  const incrementCartTotal = () => setCartTotal(cartTotal + 1)

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cartTotal,
        incrementCartTotal,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}

CartProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
}

CartProvider.defaultProps = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
}
```

**App**

```
import React from 'react'
import { CartContext, CartProvider } from './CartContext'

function CartTotalItems() {
  const { cartTotal } = React.useContext(CartContext)
  return (
    <p>
      Total items currently in cart:
      {cartTotal}
    </p>
  )
}

function AddToCart() {
  const { incrementCartTotal } = React.useContext(CartContext)
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={incrementCartTotal}>
      Add to cart
    </button>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <CartTotalItems />
      <AddToCart />
    </CartProvider>
  )
}
```

**Update**
This has worked for me, remove the 2 PropTypes and add this:

```
CartProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaking the [type of `children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) and confuses the [use of `defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#declaring-default-props):

```
// Use for initial value
CartProvider.defaultProps = {
  counter: 10,

/* 
  You declared the initial value to be the value of `PropTypes.string`
  children: PropTypes.string
*/
}
```

```
// Children are always an Array of `ReactElement`/ `ReactElement` node.
CartProvider.propTypes = {
  counter: PropTypes.number,

  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,

/* Same
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
        PropTypes.node
    ]).isRequired
*/

/*
  props.children can't be a string.
  children: PropTypes.string,
*/
}
```

Comment: this has worked for me `CartProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}` not getting any errors.

Answer (score 1):

defaultProps should be set a value instead of using Proptypes again

```
CartProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.string,
}

CartProvider.defaultProps = {
  children: "This is chidlren default string"
}
```

Comment: In console I'm getting ```checkPropTypes.js:20 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `CartProvider`, expected `string`.
    in CartProvider (created by App)
    in App```